# javascript get file type only works if file has 1 dot in name

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, file-type

I am getting the file name which includes the type from an html input,

```
var file = jQuery('#attachment')[0].files[0];
var fileType = file.name.substr(file.name.indexOf(".") + 1);
```

and this works great if the file name is FILE.TYPE but if the file name if FIlE.Name.TYPE it does not work correctly.

How can I make sure I get the last dot before the file type? Or is there a better way to go about getting the file type?

Comment: Use `.lastIndexOf('.')`.

Comment: Worked perfectly! If you make it an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` always goes from left to right and get the first match. Fortunately, there is the opposite method which goes from right to left. That method is called `.lastIndexOf()`.

```
var fileType = file.name.substr(file.name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```js
var fileType = file.name.split(".").reverse()[0];
```

This will work for any number of `.` characters

Comment: I think using `pop` is better here : `file.name.split(".").pop()`